# Entity Framework fluent one-to-one - property/navigation already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities, `Movie` and `UserRating`. I want to be able to specify table names and column names myself. `UserRating` shall have a foreign key to `Movie` in the database, but I'd like both entities in my code to have a reference to the other.

When I try to configure the relations using the fluent API in Entity Framework 7 i run into issues where creating a migrations fails due to the property/navigation already existing.

My two entity classes look like this

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public UserRating UserRating { get; set; }
}

public class UserRating
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I have two classes where I configure the mappings:

```cs
public class MovieConfig : IEntityTypeConfig<Movie>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("movie");
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
        builder.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(m => m.Title).HasColumnName("title").IsRequired();
    }
}

public class UserRatingConfig : IEntityTypeConfig<UserRating>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRating> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("user_rating");
        builder.HasKey(ur => ur.Id);
        builder.Property(ur => ur.Id).HasColumnName("id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(ur => ur.Rating).HasColumnName("rating").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(ur => ur.Movie).HasColumnName("movie_id").IsRequired();
        builder.HasOne(ur => ur.Movie).WithOne(m => m.UserRating).HasForeignKey("movie_id");
    }
}
```

And lastly the DbContext where the configs are applied:

```cs
public class MovieContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("<connection string>");

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRating> UserRatings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MovieConfig());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserRatingConfig());
    }
}
```

With this setup, when I try to run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` I get the following error:

`The property or navigation 'Movie' cannot be added to the entity type 'UserRating' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'UserRating'.`
The stacktrace originates from the last line in `UserRatingConfig`.

So it sounds like the relationship's being configured two times somehow. So I tried to prevent it being configured from `Movie`, first by setting `[NotMapped]` on the `UserRating` property. And then by specifying `builder.Ignore(m => m.UserRating);` in `MovieConfig`. Both resulted in the same error.

Okay, so what if I try to just skip configuring the relation from `UserRating`? I tried to just comment out the last line, where the stacktrace originates:

```cs
//builder.HasOne(ur => ur.Movie).WithOne(m => m.UserRating).HasForeignKey("movie_id");
```

That results in a different error message, that is even more confusing. Now I get the error: `The 'Movie' property 'UserRating.Movie' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

This makes me even more confused. So somehow I'm trying to configure the relationship two times, and if I remove the only place I know about, then I'm apparently not configuring it at all.

What do I need to change in order for this to work?

Comment: Remove wrong line `builder.Property(ur => ur.Movie)...`. `Movie` is not column.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Just removing that line, without any other changes, results in another error: `You are configuring a relationship between 'UserRating' and 'Movie' but have specified a foreign key on 'movie_id'. The foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the relationship.` Searching for that error points me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205049/one-to-one-relationship-in-entity-framework-core where they're suggesting the same solution as David Browne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to configure the relationship once, and you only need the fluent configuration *at all* if you don't have a declared foreign key property.  eg

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
                .HasOne(m => m.UserRating)
                .WithOne(r => r.Movie)
                .HasForeignKey<UserRating>(r => r.Id);
```

creates

```
      CREATE TABLE [Movie] (
          [Id] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [Title] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_Movie] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );

      CREATE TABLE [UserRating] (
          [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
          [Rating] int NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRating] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
          CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRating_Movie_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Movie] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
```

Also 1-1 relationships have bad code smell.  Just add the properties to Movie, or declare UserRating as an [Owned Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) if you want to dot into the rating properties.

Comment: The reason the user ratings are not located in the movie table is that not all movies have user ratings, and I think it's a bad design choice to have lots of null values. Then I prefer to have another table. It sounds like Owned Entity Types would also be declared in the owning table, resulting in the same issue.
Like I mentioned, I'd like to name my columns and tables myself. And I don't like to pollute my entity classes with lots of annotations, that's why I do the configuring in a separate class using the fluent API. Any way to have two tables, and name tables/columns using the fluent API?

Comment: Yes.  The configuration example I posted will create two separate tables.  You can extend that fluent mapping so specify the table and column names and column types in the normal way.

Comment: Oh. I actually tried your example, but didn't see the foreign key column that I expected. But I see now that the `id` column in `user_rating` will actually be a foreign key to `movie`. Not what I was thiking first, but that works. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's the canonical design for a 1-1 relationship because having a second column is just redundant.